# Вывести "социально дружелюбных" людей для заданной группы, зная об отношениях между отдельными людьми

Tags: python, база-данных, ооп, python-3.x, классы

Есть двадцать человек, и у каждого из них есть свои предпочтения, которые должны быть записаны в программе. Каждый человек имеет: имя, возраст, пару-тройку людей (из тех двадцати), которые ему нравятся и пару-тройку (из тех же двадцати) тех, кто ему не нравятся.

Пользователь передает в программу имена трех существующих людей, а получает на выходе список из всех человек, которые имеют хорошие отношения хотя бы с одним из этих трех (и не имеют плохих с остальными двумя).

Список должен быть в порядке убывания, сперва идут те, кто нравятся всем троим, потом те люди, которые нравятся только двоим (с третьим у них нейтральные отношения) и так далее.

---

У меня были разные идеи, но больше всего, кажется, здесь подходит класс, где 20 людей являются объектами этого класса, после некоторых раздумий решил написать сюда. Я не прошу строчить за меня код этой программы, просто объясните на словах рекомендуемый порядок действий для написания кода, как что будет выглядеть. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я разбил ваш вопрос на смысловые блоки, но постарайтесь в дальнейшем делать это сами.

Comment: В чём у вас конкретно проблема? Сложности с сортировкой полученного списка "социально дружелюбных" людей? Или сложности с составлением этого списка? Или сложности вообще как создать объект с приведёнными атрибутами? Найдите *одну* проблему, которая у вас сейчас вызывает наибольшие трудности и укажите её отредактировав ваш вопрос, иначе вопрос слишком общий. В каком виде вам даны исходные данные?  Свойство *"имеют хорошие отношения"* является взаимным или действует только в одну сторону?

Answer (score 2):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Human(dict):
    '''кажется, здесь подходит класс, где 20 людей являются объектами этого класса'''
    Humans = set()  # Есть двадцать человек

    @classmethod
    def get_humans(cls, names: [str,]) -> {object,}:
        '''вернуть инстансы Human, по имени'''
        return frozenset(human for human in cls.Humans if human['name'] in names)

    @classmethod
    def get_human(cls, name: str) -> object:
        for human in cls.Humans:
            if human['name'] == name: return human

    @staticmethod
    def key_counter(human: object, key: str, humans: [object, ]):
        return len(tuple(True for hum in humans if human in hum[key]))

    @classmethod
    def get_liked_humans(cls, *names: [str,]) -> [object,]:
        '''передает в программу имена трех существующих людей, а получает на выходе список'''
        print('\nget_liked_humans%s' % str(names))

        humans_from_args = cls.get_humans(names)
        def liked_humans():
            for human in cls.Humans:  # из всех человек
                # которые имеют хорошие отношения хотя бы с одним из этих трех
                if human['like'] & humans_from_args \
                        and not human['dislike'] & humans_from_args:  # и не имеют плохих с остальными двумя
                    yield human

        def sort_humans(human: object):
            '''кто нравятся всем троим, потом те люди, которые нравятся только двоим'''
            like = cls.key_counter(human, 'like', humans_from_args)
            human.hist.append('нравится {} людям из {}'.format(like, names))
            return like

        return list(sorted(liked_humans(),  # получает на выходе список
                           key=sort_humans,  # сперва идут те кто нравятся
                           reverse=True))  # Список должен быть в порядке убывания

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.update(kwargs)  # Каждый человек имеет: имя, возраст
        self['like'] = set()  # пару-тройку людей (из тех двадцати), которые ему нравятся
        self['dislike'] = set()  # пару-тройку людей (из тех двадцати), которые ему не нравятся
        self.hist = []  # история поиска get_liked_humans
        self.Humans.add(self)  # добавить Human

    def __call__(self, key: str, *names: [str,]):
        '''like dislike'''
        for human in self.get_humans(names):
            self[key].add(human)
            print("%s %s %s" % (human['name'], key, self['name']))

    def print(self):
        echo = []
        for k in sorted(self, reverse=True):
            echo.append('%s: %s' % (k, self[k]))

        echo.append('Всего {} <нравится({}) / не нравится({})> людям'.format(
            self, self.key_counter(self, 'like', self.Humans), self.key_counter(self, 'dislike', self.Humans)))

        echo.append(self.hist[-1])

        print('\n', '\n'.join(echo))

    def __repr__(self): return self['name']
    def __hash__(self): return id(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for r in range(20):  # где 20 людей являются объектами этого класса
        Human(name='Ivan%s' % r, age=r)  # Каждый человек имеет: имя, возраст

    h = Human.get_human
    # кто нравятся всем троим, потом те люди, которые нравятся только двоим
    h('Ivan1')('like', 'Ivan0')
    h('Ivan2')('like', 'Ivan0', 'Ivan5')
    h('Ivan3')('like', 'Ivan0', 'Ivan5')
    # у каждого из них есть свои предпочтения, которые должны быть записаны в программе
    # пару-тройку людей (из тех двадцати), которые ему нравятся и пару-тройку (из тех же двадцати) тех, кто ему не нравятся.
    h('Ivan0')('like', 'Ivan1')
    h('Ivan0')('dislike', 'Ivan8', 'Ivan4', 'Ivan5')
    h('Ivan4')('like', 'Ivan1', 'Ivan2', 'Ivan3')
    h('Ivan5')('like', 'Ivan2')
    h('Ivan6')('like', 'Ivan1')
    h('Ivan6')('dislike', 'Ivan3')
    h('Ivan7')('like', 'Ivan0')
    h('Ivan8')('like', 'Ivan3', 'Ivan1')
    h('Ivan8')('dislike', 'Ivan2')

    # Пользователь передает в программу имена трех существующих людей
    for human in Human.get_liked_humans('Ivan1', 'Ivan2', 'Ivan3'):
        human.print()
```

out:

```
Ivan0 like Ivan1
Ivan0 like Ivan2
Ivan5 like Ivan2
Ivan0 like Ivan3
Ivan5 like Ivan3
Ivan1 like Ivan0
Ivan4 dislike Ivan0
Ivan8 dislike Ivan0
Ivan5 dislike Ivan0
Ivan2 like Ivan4
Ivan1 like Ivan4
Ivan3 like Ivan4
Ivan2 like Ivan5
Ivan1 like Ivan6
Ivan3 dislike Ivan6
Ivan0 like Ivan7
Ivan1 like Ivan8
Ivan3 like Ivan8
Ivan2 dislike Ivan8

get_liked_humans('Ivan1', 'Ivan2', 'Ivan3')

 name: Ivan0
like: {Ivan1}
dislike: {Ivan4, Ivan8, Ivan5}
age: 0
Всего Ivan0 <нравится(4) / не нравится(0)> людям
нравится 3 людям из ('Ivan1', 'Ivan2', 'Ivan3')

 name: Ivan5
like: {Ivan2}
dislike: set()
age: 5
Всего Ivan5 <нравится(2) / не нравится(1)> людям
нравится 2 людям из ('Ivan1', 'Ivan2', 'Ivan3')

 name: Ivan4
like: {Ivan2, Ivan1, Ivan3}
dislike: set()
age: 4
Всего Ivan4 <нравится(0) / не нравится(1)> людям
нравится 0 людям из ('Ivan1', 'Ivan2', 'Ivan3')
```

Comment: вы отредактировали этот ответ уже дюжину раз, не могли вы пару слов добавить (в дополнение к коду), в чём основная идея ответа и что он призван научить автора (то есть как точно определены "кто ему не нравятся", время исполнения по порядку величины и "рекомендуемый порядок действий"). Наследование от dict, использование classmethod и одновременное использование `**kwargs` и type hinting выглядит необоснованным для данной задачи.